# NoClassDefFoundError at runtime using Lucene IndexableField

Tags: java, ant, runtime-error, lucene

I have written a program which uses Lucene to text match addresses for a scraper. Everything works fine in NetBeans when it's compiled and run, however when built and run from the command line, I receive the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/index/IndexableField
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
```

I've found that the class IndexableField.class is not in any of the jar files so I have no idea why it works in the first place, let alone why it doesn't work once it's built and run from the Terminal.

Comment: do you have any lucene related jars hidden somewhere? running a java app in IDE like NetBeans or Eclipse is simple cuz **Classpath** is figured out by IDE automatically. So basically two things you need to do. 1. search for jars like **lucene-*.jar**; 2. when you run the app through command line, you need to set up class path first **javac -cp**

Comment: Command line may have different class path with the NetBeans, IndexableField.class should be in the Lucene-core.jar.

Comment: Cheers guys. IndexableField was for some reason not in the core jar. Have downloaded the precompiled version (I'd been building from source) and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I met with the problem. According to Lucene  docs I add 4 Jars into classpath and solved problem.
Below is from the docs.

"Setting your CLASSPATH

First, you should download the latest Lucene distribution and then extract it to a working directory.

You need four JARs: the Lucene JAR, the queryparser JAR, the common analysis JAR, and the Lucene demo JAR. You should see the Lucene JAR file in the core/ directory you created when you extracted the archive -- it should be named something like lucene-core-{version}.jar. You should also see files called lucene-queryparser-{version}.jar, lucene-analyzers-common-{version}.jar and lucene-demo-{version}.jar under queryparser, analysis/common/ and demo/, respectively.

Put all four of these files in your Java CLASSPATH."